# left join on cake php 1.3

Tags: php, oracle, cakephp

How to create this query on cakePHP 1.3

```
 SELECT "Redeem_log"."benefit_id", count("Redeem_log"."benefit_id") as JUMLAH FROM  "redeem_logs" "Redeem_log" 
LEFT JOIN "benefits" "Benefit" ON ("Redeem_log"."benefit_id" = "Benefit"."id") 
LEFT JOIN "merchants" "Merchant" ON ("Benefit"."merchant_id" = "Merchant"."id")  
LEFT JOIN "merchant_types" "Merchant_type" ON ("Merchant"."merchant_type_id" = "Merchant_type"."id") 
WHERE "Redeem_log"."benefit_id" IS NOT NULL AND ("Merchant_type"."merchant_type"='lokal' OR "Merchant_type"."merchant_type"='nasional') GROUP BY "Redeem_log"."benefit_id"  ORDER BY "JUMLAH" DESC
```

I don't want to use belongsTO, hasMany or ect 
If I use

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Benefit' => array('className' => 'Benefit',     'foreignKey' => 'benefit_id'),
    'Merchant' => array('className' => 'Merchant', 'foreignKey' => 'merchant_id')
);
```

left join is like :

```
SELECT "Redeem_log"."benefit_id", count("Redeem_log"."benefit_id") as JUMLAH 
FROM "redeem_logs" "Redeem_log" 
LEFT JOIN "benefits" "Benefit" ON ("Redeem_log"."benefit_id" = "Benefit"."id") 
LEFT JOIN "merchants" "Merchant" ON ("Redeem_log"."merchant_id" = "Merchant"."id") 
WHERE "Redeem_log"."benefit_id" IS NOT NULL  GROUP BY "Redeem_log"."benefit_id"  
ORDER BY "JUMLAH" DESC
```

Comment: Good question, but as per cakephp documentations, if we use count method then it will only return `integer count value`, no other field is returned. So as of now we can find id and count separately. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-count

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, the params for the query looks bit scary, but when you look on it in details it makes sense:

```
$params = array(
    'recursive' => -1,
    'fields' => array('RedeemLog.benefit_id', 'COUNT(RedeemLog.benefit_id) as JUMLAH'),
    'conditions' => array(
        array('NOT' => array('RedeemLog.benefit_id' => null)),
        array('Merchanttype.merchant_type' => array('lokal', 'nasional')),
     ),
     'joins' => array(
         array(
             'table' => 'benefits',
             'alias' => 'Benefit',
             'type' => 'LEFT',
             'conditions' => array('RedeemLog.benefit_id = Benefit.id')
         ),
         array(
            'table' => 'merchants',
            'alias' => 'Merchant',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('Benefit.merchant_id = Merchant.id')
         ),
         array(
            'table' => 'merchant_types',
            'alias' => 'Merchanttype',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('Merchant.merchant_type_id = Merchanttype.id')
         ),
     ),
     'order' => 'JUMLAH DESC',
     'group' => 'RedeemLog.benefit_id',
 );
```

and finaly the cake find

```
 $result = $this->RedeemLog->find('all', $params);
```

hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add joins field in params parameter of MOdel::find();

like this

```
$params = array(
    'joins'=>array(
         array(
             'table'=>'users',
             'alias'=>'User',
             'type'=>'LEFT/RIGHT/INNER',
             'conditions'=>array("$this->Alias.foreignKey=User.pk")
         )
     )
);
```